# Enviar el Id del registro que acabo de crear a otro template

Tags: django

Buenas tardes estoy realizando una aplicación en Django 1.10 y necesito que al momento de crear un registro este me envía a otro vista con otro template el Id de este registro que acabo de crear.

views.py

```
def datosBasicos(request): #En esta vista creo el nuevo registro
    if request.method == 'POST':
        beneficiario = Beneficiario()
        beneficiario.numeroDocumento = request.POST['numeroDocumento']
        beneficiario.nombreUno = request.POST['nombreUno']
        beneficiario.save()
        ben = Beneficiario.objects.get(id=beneficiario.id)
        messages.success(request, validator.getMessage())
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/beneficiario/beneficiario_create/%d/'%ben.id)
return render(request,'datosBasicos.html', informacion)

def beneficiario_create(request, id): #Necesito que me llegue a esta vista el id del registro creado
    beneficiario = Beneficiario.objects.get(id = id)
    return render(request,'beneficiario_create.html')
```

urls.py

```
   urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', beneficiario, name='beneficiario'),
    url(r'^beneficiario_create/(?P<id>\d+)/$', beneficiario_create,    name='beneficiario_create'),    
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes que tal, si lo que quieres renderizar los datos del objeto recien creado en el template, no veo necesario que quieras enviarlo a una vista nueva.

Simplemente renderiza el template de una vez al momento de ejecutar la acción, en vez de colocar el `return HttpResponseRedirect`

finalizaas tu view con un

`render_to_response("beneficiario_create.html", locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))`

Si deseas tener otra vista donde se manejen y se puedan visualizar los detalles de objeto le puedes llamar detalles de beneficiario, donde si recibes el id

quedaría algo como:

```
def datosBasicos(request, id = None): #En esta vista creo el nuevo registro
    if request.method == 'POST':
        beneficiario = Beneficiario()
        beneficiario.numeroDocumento = request.POST['numeroDocumento']
        beneficiario.nombreUno = request.POST['nombreUno']
        beneficiario.save()
        ben = Beneficiario.objects.get(id=beneficiario.id)
        messages.success(request, validator.getMessage())
        render_to_response("beneficiario_create.html", locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        # aca deberías tener un blque para considerar que hacer en caso de que la peticion sea get, asumo debe venir el ID en la url y cargar la informacion
        id = request.GET["id"]
        beneficiario = Beneficiario.objects.get(id = id)
        return render(request,'datosBasicos.html', locals(), context_instance = RequestContext(request))

# Este view esta demas
# def beneficiario_create(request, id): #Necesito que me llegue a esta vista el id del registro # creado
#     beneficiario = Beneficiario.objects.get(id = id)
#     return render(request,'beneficiario_create.html')
```

Saludos, y espero mi respuesta te sea de ayuda